# How do I get a different UIImage Array every time I click a button?

Tags: arrays, swift

So basically I have a button and I need my UIImage to change randomly to one of three images in my array every time I click the button. Right now what happens when I click the button, is it just picks a random image and then when I click it again the image stays the same.

Here's what I have written inside my button:

```
@IBAction func scissorButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    playerChoice.image = scissor.png
    computerChoice.image = computerArray[randomChoice]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you generated a random number once and stored that result in `randomChoice`. But you need to generate a new random number each time the button is tapped.

The simplest option is to do:

```
@IBAction func scissorButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    computerChoice.image = computerArray.randomElement()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to guarantee that each time you click the button will get a new non-similar random image

```
var old = 0

@IBAction func scissorButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
   var randomChoice = 0
   while randomChoice == old {
     randomChoice = Int.random(in: 0..<computerArray.count)
   } 
   old = randomChoice
   computerChoice.image = computerArray[randomChoice]
}
```

Comment: Assuming `old` is set to a random number before this selector is called, you need to initialize `randomChoice` to `old`, not `0`.

Comment: I dont' compile this Xcode isn't in front me 90% of time , assigning it to `old` or `0` won't make difference if at last the while terminate when they are not equal

Comment: Once `old` isn't `0`, your code only shows image `0` and not a random value. So yes, it does make a difference in how you initialize `randomChoice`.

Comment: isn't this depend on assumption of knowing the random value ? i guess we shouldn't depend any expectation beyond it

Comment: It only depends on your own code. At some point you will end up setting `old` to some random value other than `0`. On the next button press your code will only show image `0`. Then a random image. Then only image `0`, etc. Your code will always show image `0` instead of any other random image whenever `old` is not `0`. It doesn't matter what the very first value of `old` is.

Comment: yes , but imagine it's `var randomChoice = old` can't this be happen from the random itself ?

Comment: With that small change, it guarantees the loop will be entered at least once and a new random number will be generated. That's what you want to avoid the problem of always returning `0` when `old` is something other than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it's work fine for me:

```
//Have an array of the name for your image like
let img = ["img1","img2","img3","img4"]

@IBAction func randomImageClick(_ sender: Any){

  self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: img[Int.random(in: img.count)]) // Look out for range of index. its size must be equal your array count, otherwise it'll get index out of range
}
```

Comment: The use of `DispatchQueue` won't be needed since button handlers are always called on the main queue.

Comment: Why hardcode the range of `0..<4`? Use `img.count`.